# Pentaho Report with Kettle as Data source

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration, xaction

I am trying to call a kettle transformation using a pentaho report. My transformation will retrieve a resultset from table based on a command line argument. The report generates the correct output if i remove the command line argument from the ktr and run the hard coded SELECT sql. but it retrieves empty when we pass command line arguments/parameters.

The report works good when i click preview with arguments, but not working after i publish it.

My parameters are not getting passed to the kettle transformation.

Report Parameter: ondate
Kettle Named parameter: ONDATE (I have mapped both in my report)

did i miss something?

Comment: thats weird. put a writetolog step in the transformation to be sure what is happening.  Also check the server logs carefully, this should work.

Comment: Hi codek, Removed the command line argument and added it to Kettle Named Parameter. now my report working fine.
Now facing another issue, I am using Dropdowns in my report parameters. for that i have created a sql. and the report now says,
    "ERROR [ReportContentGenerator] The specified query is not executable here." searched but got no solution in google

Comment: thats a separate question. glad you got the original thing working

Answer (score 0):

Please check with other parameter display types also.

If the issue persists try with adding 'top 1' to select query and use 'singlevaluequery("parameterqueryname")' in default value field.

Or else please change the position of the parameter in the parameter list in data pane  and check whether the issue persists.